How do I correctly escape complex command lines in chezmoi?
I'm chezmoi-ifying my dotfiles, and I feel like this should be simple, but it isn't. I want to take the result of this command line:
system_profiler SPHardwareDataType | grep 'Serial Number (system)' | awk '{print $4}'
and drop it into a variable in chezmoi:
{{- $serialNumber := "Unknown" -}}

{{- if eq .chezmoi.os "darwin" -}}
    {{- $serialNumber := output "sh" "-c" "system_profiler SPHardwareDataType | grep 'Serial Number (system)' | awk '{print $4}'" -}}
{{- end -}}

[data]
    serial_number = {{ $serialNumber | quote }}

Should be simple, but however I escape that "$4" at the end, I get an error.
I'd be happy enough with:
{{- $serialNumber := output "my_command_wrapped_in_a_shell_script.sh" -}}
but I can't find an "official" way for chezmoi to include shell scripts that aren't part of the run_* family.
If someone schools me on the intricacies of escaping, I'll be delighted. I feel this should be a lot simpler than it is.
I'vce tried Google, chatbots, official docs, throwing blackslashes around randomly, banging on the keyboard...

As an aside, you want to avoid the useless grep; system_profiler SPHardwareDataType | awk '/Serial Number \(system\)/ {print $4}'

According to the doc you can call a shell script if you use an absolute path: /path/to/script.sh

DISCLAIMER: This isn't an answer about the escaping of chezmoi's output command.
You might not have seen it; the example of chezmoi's ioreg command is about getting the Platform Serial Number on macOS.
{{ if eq .chezmoi.os "darwin" }}
{{   $serialNumber := index ioreg "IORegistryEntryChildren" 0 "IOPlatformSerialNumber" }}
{{ end }}

It should yield the same result as the following with output:
system_profiler SPHardwareDataType | awk '/Serial Number/ {print $NF}'


Has to be best possible answer, doesn't it? Solves the problem I've actually got, not the problem I think I've got.
I'd still love to know how to escape that command correctly, though.

Sorry, I didn't find the string escaping in the doc, and I cannot test chezmoi on my own. Did you try to backslash-escape the $ in your awk code?
